# Is sortedArrayUsingComparator a safe way to randomize a NSArray?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random, comparison, nsarray

I was messing around with `NSArray` functions earlier, and I think I may have happened across the easiest way to randomize a NSArray:

```
NSArray *randomize(NSArray *arr)
{
    return [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return arc4random_uniform(3) - 1; // one of -1, 0, or 1
    }];
}
```

Which, in theory, should randomize the NSArray thoroughly. However, after considerable thinking, I was wondering if this could possibly be unsafe, and theoretically turn into an infinite loop, depending on the sort algorithms used by NSArray.

I tested this on arrays on sizes of 10 - 100000, and I saw a linear performance difference (about `N * (log10(N) + 2)` comparisons per randomization), which isn't bad.

However, is there ever a situation that could arise where the NSArray could never theoretically sort itself, and cause an application crash? It seems to me that it shouldn't happen, but you never know.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm runs in time O(N) and guarantees a truly uniform random array as output.  It's faster that what you've suggested, really easy to code up, and should put all your worries at bay.  That said, this is a really cool question, and I'm definitely going to play around with it!

Comment: @templatetypedef however, that only works with a mutable array. In objective-c, you would have to have the overhead of a mutable array, which is arguably the same performance difference.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about Objective-C.  Thanks for pointing that out!  (That said, is the cost of making a mutable array, copying the elements over, Fisher-Yates shuffling it, then copying it back all that high?)

Comment: @templatetypedef in objective-c, it can be. Unfortunately, NSArray is a class-cluster, so we have no details on the implementation, we can only make benchmarks

Comment: @templatetypedef i wrote and profiled this. results below, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends on the underlying sorting algorithm.

Consider what would happen if the underlying sort is a bubble sort.  This means that any time you compare a pair of elements, there is a 1/3 chance that you will swap them (if the comparison makes them appear out of order).  Consequently, if you were to sort an array of n elements with this comparison function, the probability that the algorithm terminates at each step is equal to the probability that none of the comparisons evaluate to "out of order."  Since each comparison says "out of order" with probability 1/3, this means that the probability that the algorithm terminates on each iteration is (2/3)<sup>n</sup>.  This means that the expected number of iterations before the algorithm terminates is (3/2)<sup>n</sup> = 3<sup>n</sup> / 2<sup>n</sup>.  If you try running this algorithm for a reasonably-sized array (say, n = 1000), then the expected number of iterations is going to be staggeringly huge; n = 1000 gives 1.233840597×10<sup>176</sup> expected iterations!  This algorithm will eventually terminate, but the expected runtime is so long that from a practical perspective it's effectively infinite.

On the other hand, if you try using a different algorithm, such as selection sort, you are not guaranteed to get a uniform distribution.  For example, consider the very first pass of the algorithm, which will find the element to put at position 1.  Every element in the array should (if the distribution really is uniform) have probability 1/n of being placed first.  But this is not the case.  Note that the first element will be kept in the first position unless it is swapped with something.  This occurs only if the comparison comes up +1 (or -1, depending on the internals) at any point during the first scan.  The probability that all the comparisons come back with a different value is (2/3)<sup>n-1</sup>, which is not the same as 1/n.  In fact, it's astronomically unlikely that the first element in the sequence will end up at the front once you're done sorting.  Consequently, even though the algorithm will terminate, there is no guarantee that you get a uniformly random distribution.

If you try using something like quicksort, heapsort, or mergesort, then the algorithm will eventually terminate, but I'm not sure whether or not it's guaranteed to be random.  I'll think about whether this is uniformly random for a bit and then update my answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know from some stack traces that for certain sizes of arrays, NSArray uses a merge sort. However, this is not guaranteed, and that is one of the issues with this method of randomization. Thus, I asked the question specifically for NSArray, not arrays in general.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII- From the docs I found (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), I don't see any indication that the underlying algorithm has to be merge sort.  Is this guaranteed?  Also, would you mind updating your question to make very explicit that you are only concerned with `NSArray` in this context, and not the more general question of "what happens if you sort an array with a randomized comparator?"

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that NSArray uses a more-or-less standard stable merge-sort algorithm. It's probably best if the comparator returns only -1 and 1, since mergesort does not compare elements to themselves.

For a four-element array 1 2 3 4, mergesort randomizes the first and second halves, then merges. If L = [a b] = [1 2] or [2 1], and R = [c d] = [3 4] or [4 3], the merge decision tree (with non-decisions suppressed) looks like

```
       [a b c d]   [a c b d]
      /           /
   [a]-------[a c]-[a c d b]
  /
[]
  \   
   [c]-------[c a]-[c a b d]
      \           \
       [c d a b]   [c a d b]
```

Sequences of the form [L L R R] (e.g., [1 2 3 4], [2 1 3 4], [1 2 4 3], [2 1 4 3]) should be total probability 1/6 (each 1/24) but are probability 1/4. Ditto for [R R L L]. Sequences of the form [L R L R] should be total probability 1/6 but are probability 1/8. Ditto for [L R R L], [R L L R], [R L R L]. *This is not uniform.*

**More importantly**, you're violating the contract (apparently implicit in the docs I read, but close variants of this contract are extremely common) that the comparator give deterministic answers consistent with a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). This means that Apple's code is free to violate its end of the contract by throwing an exception or not terminating. Will it indeed run forever? Probably not, but if it did, and you filed a bug report to Apple, they'd have a laugh and WONTFIX you. I think most programmers would agree with them. It's not a good habit to rely on unspecified aspects of a software library.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle

templatetypedef also commented on this.

Fisher-Yates Shuffling a `mutableCopy` is plenty fast, and a better randomization. For small arrays (10 elements), your proposal is slightly faster than the Fisher-Yates shuffle, as implemented below. For large arrays (1000000 elements) the Fisher_Yates is 4 times faster than yours. If you are ok with returning the mutable copy you made, then the Fisher-Yates is faster for 10 elements as well.

I'd go with the superior shuffle algo, which is fast for both small and large sizes.

Here's the program -- you know how to use Instruments!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSArray * imp_RandomizeUsingSortedArrayUsingComparator(NSArray * arr) {
    return [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return arc4random_uniform(3) - 1; // one of -1, 0, or 1
    }];
}
__attribute__((__noinline__)) static void RandomizeUsingSortedArrayUsingComparator(NSArray * arr) {
    @autoreleasepool { imp_RandomizeUsingSortedArrayUsingComparator(arr); }
}

static NSArray * imp_RandomizeUsingMutableCopy(NSArray * arr) {
    if (1 >= arr.count) {
        return [arr.copy autorelease];
    }
    NSMutableArray * cp = [arr.mutableCopy autorelease];
    u_int32_t i = (u_int32_t)cp.count;
    while (i > 1) {
        --i;
        const u_int32_t j = arc4random_uniform(i);
        [cp exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
    }
    // you may not favor creating the concrete copy
    return [cp.copy autorelease];
}

__attribute__((__noinline__)) static void RandomizeUsingMutableCopy(NSArray * arr) {
    @autoreleasepool { imp_RandomizeUsingMutableCopy(arr); }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray * filled = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            [filled addObject:@""];
        }

        NSArray * concrete = filled.copy;
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            RandomizeUsingSortedArrayUsingComparator(concrete);
            RandomizeUsingMutableCopy(concrete);
        }
        [concrete release];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I do not want a mutable array. The idea was to operate directly on an NSArray.